# How to pass the system.getproperty values when triggering the build remotely

Tags: java, jenkins

Currently i am using the below option (refer the below screenshot) to send the username and password to pass these to the java program (i will access the username and password using System.getProperty("user"). But when triggering jenkins job remotely i don't know how to pass these (username and password) as these values gets changed every now and then. So my question is how do i pass these when using the remote url (http://localhost:8080/job/Test/build?token=xyz)

[image: Jenkins screenshot]

Comment: What do you mean by "triggering remotely"? What is the difference between opening a browser page to your localhost and a remote system?

Comment: By calling the jenkins job using the url and i want to pass the user and pass parameters in the url itself, so that i can access in the java program using the system.getproperty()

Comment: Please ignore this question. I have got it incorrectly.

Comment: I think you want to look into https://jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-credentials/ for example.

Comment: Thing is: you shouldnt send passwords or ids over the network in urls. Jenkins has a lot of infrastructure in place to do that. Finally: there is no "ignore the question". Instead: delete it please!

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're using Maven, and this issue here is likely the fact that Maven requires the options to be set *before* the goals.  So you'd need to use:

```
-Duser=username -Dpass=password clean install
```

Comment: So my question is how do i pass these user and pass values when triggering the jenkins job remotely by using this url (http://localhost:8080/job/Test/build?token=xyz)?
Can use additional query parameters like user=abc&pass=xyz like that!!

Comment: 1) You are free to put the system properties everywhere in the command line that calls Maven. 2) OP's question is not how to fill the Maven command line, but how to pass parameters in the URL that triggers a Jenkins job down to the Maven command.

Comment: Please ignore this question. I have got it incorrectly.